# Trying to get dynamic slideshow text. NO fixed height on container. See fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the text "WE CREATE DANCE" "WE HAVE FUN" "WE LOOK GOOD"  to be inside a container that will adjust depending on the size of the text and the number of lines of text. The size of the container is unknown because it is dynamic. I can't add a height to this container .slide. I would like the container to adjust according to the text size. If I take out the position: absolute from the child elements, the text is how I want it...however, doing this breaks the slideshow. So that will not work. I have picked this slideshow code because it was very small. So I would like to keep it small and only add some lines of code. I don't want to add an entire framework. I am using jquery and would like to keep that in.

You will see now that the slideshow text overlaps with the text underneath it. I am trying to push the bottom text down.

http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/16/

Thanks in advance for your help. I hope I can finally get this working :)

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slider-item intro secondary">WE CREATE DANCE</div>
<div class="slider-item intro secondary">WE HAVE FUN</div>
<div>
```

--

```
var InfiniteRotator = {
init: function() {
    //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
    var initialFadeIn = 1000;

    //interval between items (in milliseconds)
    var itemInterval = 5000;

    //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
    var fadeTime = 500;

    //count number of items
    var numberOfItems = $('.slider-item').length;

    //set current item
    var currentItem = 0;

    //show first item
    $('.slider-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

    //loop through the items        
    var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
        $('.slider-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

        if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
            currentItem = 0;
        } else {
            currentItem++;
        }
        $('.slider-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

    }, itemInterval);
}
}

$(document).ready(function() { //start after HTML, images have loaded

// check if there is one image or more
if($('.slider > div').length > 1){
    // run slider
    InfiniteRotator.init();

}else{
    // just one image don't slide
    alert('just one image');
    $('.slider-item').eq(0).fadeIn();
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way in my opinion using CSS:

```js
var InfiniteRotator = {
    init: function() {

        //interval between items (in milliseconds)
        var itemInterval = 5000;
      
        //loop through the items        
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
            var current = $(".slider-item.visible").removeClass('visible');

            var next = current.next();
            next = next.length ? next : current.siblings().first();
            next.addClass('visible');
          
        }, itemInterval);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() { //start after HTML, images have loaded
  
    // check if there is one image or more
    if($('.slider > div').length > 1){
        // run slider
        InfiniteRotator.init();
    }
});
```

```css
.slidermwtext {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.slider-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slider-item.visible {
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-item intro secondary visible">WE CREATE DANCE</div>
    <div class="slider-item intro secondary">WE HAVE<br> FUN</div>
    <div class="slider-item intro secondary">WE LOOK GOOD</div>
</div>

 <p class="slidermwtext"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p>
```

Comment: Hi Josh. I really wanted to paragraph text (below slideshow) to be pushed down if the slideshow text goes to 2 lines. Your solution has the same effect as adding a height to the container...so it really won't work.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that. See my CSS example.

Comment: I'm going to use this code. But before I go, can you tell me if I can add back in some of the code you took out? Like the crossfade: //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
    var fadeTime = 500;

Comment: That's accounted for in the CSS transition property. 500 milliseconds == 0.5s.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this is what you mean](http://jsfiddle.net/wcxs1q51/),

If Im understanding you correctly, you need to set your height on your `slider-item` class to `height: auto;` and remove `position: absolute:

```
slider-item {
display: none;

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

But you'll notice that your `fadeIn` on the new text triggers too early, this is because you need to pass a `callback function` to the `fadeOut()` function that is called when the animation completes. I'll update the fiddle in a moment to show you this extra addition.

Comment: I think you might have something here. I will wait for your updated fiddle. Because taking out the position: absolute makes the slideshow text not really work that great. I will wait for your response. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Leemo. I think you are on the right track with this solution. I hope it will work once you update it. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Have updated your markup, Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/9xn19111/17/)

```
<div class="slidermwtext"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-item intro secondary">WE CREATE DANCE</div>
    <div class="slider-item intro secondary">WE HAVE FUN</div>
    <div class="slider-item intro secondary">WE LOOK GOOD</div>
</div>

  magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want the slideshow text to be inside the paragraph text. I just want the slide text to push the paragraph down.

Comment: That works, but the fading text should be on the same line. Not jumping up and down.

Comment: It's because of the fading effect used.

Comment: That is working. but is there no way to keep the fade transition? I really wanted to keep that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your issue.

**JQuery:**

```
$('.slider-item').eq(currentItem).delay(510).fadeIn(fadeTime);
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider-item {
    font-size: 22px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check [Fiddle HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/21/)